# API search for term rather than id

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to use USDA FoodData API. My code currently works by typing in the FDCID of a food item and displays the protein in the food item on the screen.

What I want to do is create a web app where a user can search for a food by its name rather than by the FDCID.

Looking through the documentation I dont see a way for users to search by food name, yet on their website they have a search funtionality setup so that you can do just that.

I am wondering if there is a function I can setup to get the FDCID by searching for a foodname and then passing the ID into the search. Or if there is a better way to do this.

here is a link to the documentation also:
https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
require('dotenv').config();




export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    protein: ""
  }


  clickHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      const query = event.target.value;
      const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY
      axios.get(`https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/food/${query}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(res => {

          const protein = res['data']['foodNutrients']['0']['amount'];
          this.setState({ protein })
        })
    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.protein}</h1>
        <input onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
      </div>
    )
  }


}
```

Comment: Does this endpoint work for you: https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=Cheddar%20Cheese ?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I Was looking for, I did not see this, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [/search?api_key=KEY&query=QUERY](https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=Cheddar%20Cheese) endpoint.

[Swagger Docs](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/fdcnal/food-data_central_api/1.0.0#/FDC/getFoodsSearch)